# how can I select rows in a Dataframe according to specified conditions in several columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in pandas and trying to get some rows which match conditions of two columns

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sp500.csv')

full_list = []




symbol = df['Symbol']
full_list.append(symbol)
name = df['Name']
full_list.append(name)
sector = df['Sector']
full_list.append(sector)
price = df['Price']
full_list.append(price)
book_value = df['Book Value']
full_list.append(book_value)
low = df['52 week low']
full_list.append(low)
high = df['52 week high']
full_list.append(high)


df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
df = df.T

print(df.loc[df['Sector'].isin(['Financials','Energy']) and (df['52 week low'] < 80)])
```

I can't find the correct command in the documentation, and the problem is in the last line of code. Please help me to understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close. You need to use bit-wise operators and take care to consider the unintuitive operator precedence:

```py
df.loc[
    df['Sector'].isin(['Financials','Energy']) &  # not "and"
    (df['52 week low'] < 80) # these parenthesis are crucial
]
```

Side note, without seeing the text file that you're working from, I can't help but think you'd be better off selecting your columns directly instead of rebuilding your dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
cols_to_keep = ['Symbol', 'Name', 'Sector', 'Price', 'Book Value', '52 week low', '52 week high']
rows_to_keep = lambda df: df['Sector'].isin(['Financials','Energy']) & (df['52 week low'] < 80)

df = (
    pd.read_csv('sp500.csv')
        .loc[row_to_keep, cols_to_keep]
)
```

Comment: and thanks for explaining how too choose columns easier and faster))

Answer (score 0):

So close!

```
df.loc[df['Sector'].isin(['Financials','Energy']) & (df['52 week low'] < 80)]
```